# Get JSON with where condition mysql

Tags: mysql, json

I have JSON value in column :

```
INSERT INTO `bt_product` (`_Price`) VALUES
('{\"245\":\"10\",\"366\":\"5\",\"688\":\"1\"}'),
('{\"26\":\"1\"}'),
('{\"32\":\"1\"}'),
('{\"52\":\"1\"}'),
('{\"42\":\"1\"}'),
('{\"58\":\"1\"}'),
('{\"52\":\"1\"}'),
('{\"48\":\"1\"}'),
('{\"32\":\"1\"}'),
('{\"442\":\"10\",\"494\":\"5\",\"520\":\"1\"}'),
('{\"270\":\"10\",\"302\":\"5\",\"318\":\"1\"}'),
('{\"187\":\"10\",\"209\":\"5\",\"220\":\"1\"}'),
('{\"461\":\"10\",\"515\":\"5\",\"542\":\"1\"}'),
('{\"456\":\"10\",\"509\":\"5\",\"536\":\"1\"}'),
('{\"394\":\"10\",\"441\":\"5\",\"464\":\"1\"}'),
('{\"417\":\"10\",\"466\":\"5\",\"490\":\"1\"}'),
('{\"146\":\"10\",\"163\":\"5\",\"172\":\"1\"}'),
('{\"146\":\"10\",\"163\":\"5\",\"172\":\"1\"}'),
('{\"102\":\"10\",\"114\":\"5\",\"120\":\"1\"}'),
('{\"248\":\"10\",\"277\":\"5\",\"292\":\"1\"}'),
('{\"279\":\"10\",\"312\":\"5\",\"328\":\"1\"}'),
('{\"32\":\"1\"}'),
('{\"22\":\"1\"}'),
('{\"58\":\"1\"}');
```

I need to get data between Max key and Min key.

Comment: With the given data - what is the expected output? And what did you try so far?

Comment: What is a "key"?  Please don't store data in JSON when you need SQL to access it.  What you showed should be a few dozen rows in a table.